# HTML and CSS rotate horizontal tree to vertical

Tags: html, css

I have a horizontal tree. 
How to rotate the tree vertically?
I want something like this https://1drv.ms/i/s!Ai5kxq1lzB-AnW9COefuCe8fzgHM
This is a code for horizontal tree:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ai5kxq1lzB-AnXCO3tt0ZmA3XFRK

Comment: 1.) if this is really an html/css question you need to show your markup. 2.) this sounds like a homeowner problem so please post your attempts. We're not here to do your homework for you

Answer (score 0):

This is my code:

```html
<style>

.tree ul {
 padding-top: 20px; position: relative;
 
 transition: all 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
 float: left; text-align: center;
 list-style-type: none;
 position: relative;
 padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
 
 transition: all 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li::before, .tree li::after{
 content: '';
 position: absolute; top: 0; right: 50%;
 border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
 width: 50%; height: 20px;
}
.tree li::after{
 right: auto; left: 50%;
 border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.tree li:only-child::after, .tree li:only-child::before {
 display: none;
}

.tree li:only-child{ padding-top: 0;}


.tree li:first-child::before, .tree li:last-child::after{
 border: 0 none;
}

.tree li:last-child::before{
 border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.tree li:first-child::after{
 border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}


.tree ul ul::before{
 content: '';
 position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%;
 border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
 width: 0; height: 20px;
}

.tree li a{
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 padding: 5px 10px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #666;
 font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
 font-size: 11px;
 display: inline-block;
 
 border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 
 transition: all 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li a:hover, .tree li a:hover+ul li a {
 background: #c8e4f8; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}

.tree li a:hover+ul li::after, 
.tree li a:hover+ul li::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul ul::before{
 border-color:  #94a0b4;
}

.myButton {
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px #f0f7fa;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px #f0f7fa;
 box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px #f0f7fa;
 background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #33bdef), color-stop(1, #019ad2));
 background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #33bdef 5%, #019ad2 100%);
 background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #33bdef 5%, #019ad2 100%);
 background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #33bdef 5%, #019ad2 100%);
 background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #33bdef 5%, #019ad2 100%);
 background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #33bdef 5%, #019ad2 100%);
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#33bdef', endColorstr='#019ad2',GradientType=0);
 background-color:#33bdef;
 -moz-border-radius:6px;
 -webkit-border-radius:6px;
 border-radius:6px;
 border:1px solid #057fd0;
 display:inline-block;
 cursor:pointer;
 color:#ffffff;
 font-family:Arial;
 font-size:15px;
 font-weight:bold;
 padding:6px 24px;
 text-decoration:none;
 text-shadow:0px -1px 0px #5b6178;
}
.myButton:hover {
 background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #019ad2), color-stop(1, #33bdef));
 background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #019ad2 5%, #33bdef 100%);
 background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #019ad2 5%, #33bdef 100%);
 background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #019ad2 5%, #33bdef 100%);
 background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #019ad2 5%, #33bdef 100%);
 background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #019ad2 5%, #33bdef 100%);
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#019ad2', endColorstr='#33bdef',GradientType=0);
 background-color:#019ad2;
}
.myButton:active {
 position:relative;
 top:1px;
}

.tree li a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #666;
 font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
 font-size: 11px;
 
}

</style>

<a href="file:///D:/Downloads/horizontal.html" class="myButton">Horizontal</a>
<a href="file:///D:/Downloads/Vertical.html" class="myButton">Vertical</a>

<div class="tree">
 <ul>
  <li>
   <a href="#">Parent</a>
   <ul>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Child</a>
     <ul>
      <li>
       <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Child</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a></li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
       <ul>
        <li>
         <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
        </li>
        <li>
         <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
        </li>
        <li>
         <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
        </li>
       </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```